# Why is my tasks's CPU usage not showing in the graph in htop?

Tags: ubuntu, htop

[image]

CPU is holding at a steady 200% (task is CPU-bound), but it is not showing in the graph. Why not?

Comment: What do other tools report? Say top, dstat

Comment: @niglesias `top` reports 100% usage.

Comment: `htop` gets the data from `/proc/stat`. What does `cat /proc/stat` say?